# Animation time based on quaternion difference

Tags: c#, 3d, quaternions, ogre

I'm trying to adjust the orientation of my camera using two quaternions, based on their difference. So for a minimal rotation, I want the animation to take little time, and a bigger rotation to take longer. I guess I want to rotate the camera at a certain velocity.

Is there any way to combine the yaw, roll and pitch to get a single radian, so I can use that to calculate what percentage of the quaternion I want to apply each frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you vant to differenciate the two quaternion just use the [ToAngleAxis](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1Quaternion.html#a9c516d6b499410b2fc72524026d3a124) of the delta quaternion. It returns the angle (you need this) and the axix of the rotation between the two quaternions.

You can use quaternions and the calculated speed to calculate [spherical interpolation](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1Quaternion.html#ab0c47f1a7308ac4c17db9f9ddb6e4a72) (slerp for short), which allows you to calculate intermediate states for your camera orientation.

Comment: Thanks! Although this seems to work for most angles, I sometimes get a NaN (I believe this happens when the direction lines up with the axis). Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like this is caused by a bug in Ogre: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=426695

Comment: Experiment with this, if it is a bug I can't help it.